# How To Approach Fit Method Selection for SARIMAX Models

Tags: time-series, arima, optimization, statsmodels

I am building SARIMAX models using the statsmodels library in Python.  Some of these models are single variable models and some are multi variable models.

In general, I am finding that I get very different model fits depending on my selection for the method parameter in the fit method.  The documentation lists the following options: (1) Newton-Raphson, (2) Nelder-Mead, (3) Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno (BFGS), (4) limited-memory BFGS with optional box constraints, (5) modified Powell’s method, (6) conjugate gradient, (7) Newton-conjugate gradient, (8) global basin-hopping solver

Are there any rules of thumb in terms of which method (i.e. solver) should be used in which circumstance?

For example, might one say that one should use the default for single variable models and the conjugate gradient method for multi-variable models?

I can provide an example of the kinds of differences I am seeing in model fits if that would be helpful.